# Specify multiple input files for a hadoop job

Tags: file, input, hadoop

Is there a way to specify multiple input files for a hadoop job?
I've tried separation using ',' but that didnt' work...any other suggestions?

I was able to do so...by writing my own method to do a split based off of the splitter selected and then adding the newly created paths to the job conf

Comment: Are you passing this as a command line argument to your hadoop call or are you doing this programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a directory as the input path and it will process all files in that directory.